# R: why is plot of time series much cleaner than original

Tags: r, time-series

I tried plotting original data, say dt, and compared the plot obtained by making it into a ts object, i.e.,

```
plot(dt)
```

versus

```
plot(ts(dt))
```

The first plot is very hard to visualize, while second one looks great. I then tried to see result of

```
ts(dt)-dt
```

The result was all 0s, so apparently R did not manipulate data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, `plot.ts` makes a line graph, while `plot` of a vector makes a point graph. That's the only difference.

`plot(1:10)
plot(ts(1:10))`

Comment: yeah, that seems only difference...I thought its doing some smoothing